# AWS Pinpoint push notification history

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

Is there a way to retrieve previously sent push notifications using Pinpoint programatically for a given device (endpoint ID/ device ID)?

I'm not sure if that is possible. Don't seem to be able to find a way to do it.

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. A recommended approach would be to export events to s3 and from there use Athena to query for all the campaign send events associated with that endpoint id.

The campaign send events will be have a campaign identifiers, then for each campaign id present in the campaign send events. Lastly, you could use that information in GET campaigns API to get the campaign message associate with it